# How to get local testnet account for use with scatter

Tags: accounts, testnet, scatter

I'm running a chain locally.

Making accounts with cleos and interacting with contracts is easy to understand.

But now i want to use my contract with scatter.

I tried importing the private keys of my testnet wallet, then created accounts with cleos, why arent the accounts showing up in scatter?

Is there a different account creation method i'm missing?

How can i get a local test chain account imported into scatter?

My scatter is picking up the chain and all the config seems to be correct, I have cors on my chain and everything is working up until is looks for an account.

thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Before you create the account in Scatter, you'll want to add your local testnet's chain ID and API endpoint (probably 127.0.0.1).  From there, you can import your keys and create an account while setting the local testnet you just added as the chain of choice.

### [image]

### [image]

### Select New Network top right

### [image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, i actually added the testnet config already. And this is old version of scatter. But judging by your response, exacly how i am doing it should add the accounts to scatter so i must have something setup wrong. cheers.

Comment: Gotcha.  Well if you want a code example, here's how I implemented scatter: https://github.com/NatPDeveloper/eos-chess/blob/master/js/lib/scatter-js/scatter.js